# Java multi-level generic class casting

Tags: java, generics, casting

I have a cast that is failing:

```
(Map<String, ? extends ISeries<Date, Double, ISeriesPoint<Date, Double>>>) inputSeries
```

I get the error:

```
incompatible types: java.util.Map<java.lang.String,com.quantcomponents.marketdata.IOHLCTimeSeries> 
cannot be converted to java.util.Map<java.lang.String,? extends 
com.quantcomponents.core.model.ISeries<java.util.Date,java.lang.Double,
com.quantcomponents.core.model.ISeriesPoint<java.util.Date,java.lang.Double>>>
```

inputSeries is defined as:

```
Map<String, IOHLCTimeSeries> inputSeries = createInputSeriesFromStockDatabases(inputStockDatabases);
```

createInputSeriesFromStockDatabases returns a `Map<String, IOHLCTimeSeries>`

Here are the interface definitions:

```
public interface ISeries<A extends Comparable<A>, O extends Comparable<O>, P extends ISeriesPoint<A, O>> extends Iterable<P>, IPersistentIdentifiable { ... }

public interface ITimeSeries<P extends ISeriesPoint<Date, Double>> extends ISeries<Date, Double, P>     { ... }

public interface IOHLCTimeSeries extends ITimeSeries<IOHLCPoint>, IStockDataCollection {...}
```

The cast seems to follow the interface generics, though I can't find the error. Can anyone detect it?

Thanks

Comment: How does the declaration of `IOHLCPoint` look like?

Comment: public interface IOHLCPoint extends IOHLC, ISeriesPoint<Date, Double> {...}

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it's inside a `Map`.

It's easier to see what's going on with a `List`, because that only takes one type parameter. `String` is a subclass of `Object`, and thus a `String` can be cast as an `Object`. You might expect that to mean that a `List<String>` can be cast as a `List<Object>`, but it can't: the type system can't "see" inside the outer type.

You've got the same thing going on. Just because `T` can be cast as `V` doesn't mean that `Map<String,T>` can be cast as `Map<String,V>`.

(It's incredibly annoying: it means, for example, that you can't treat an `ArrayList<ArrayList<T>>` as a `List<List<T>>`.)

Comment: Strange, this is part of a really large library -- It all compiles except for this one line. I'll try asking the author.